# Error on Flutter widget build function with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

I've created a class with 2 arguments, and 'title' is non-nullable and 'leading' is nullable.

So I defined two possible cases with if statement, for when 'leading' is null and not null.

(I refered this article: [Understanding null safety | Dart](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#flow-analysis))
But on VS Code, following error is continuously displayed:

> The element type 'Icon?' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. (dartlist_element_type_not_assignable)

What should I do to treat a null safety problem on this situation?

```
class MyPageListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text title;
  final Icon? leading;

  MyPageListTile({this.leading, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (leading is Icon) {
      return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [leading, SizedBox(width: 10), title]);
    } else {
      return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [title]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with checking `leading != null` ? If the issue persists inside the `if` try adding a bang operator (!) to title.

Comment: @esentis Ok, I haven't been known about bang operator and why it exists in dart. Just now I googled about it, applied it on my code, and it works. Thanks a lot! XD

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
final Icon? leading;
```

with

```
final Widget? leading;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly it didn't worked. '

Comment: in which line you are getting error?